# Difference between Sharepoint Foundation Server and Enterprise edition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

We have sharepoint 2010 foundation server for development and enterprise edition in live. We have one .NET web part which create a site based on the logic which works fine in development server(Foundation). Same code we used in live(Enterprise edition) creates the site first time but not the second time.

What is our problem here? I shared the  code which  create the site

```
    private void CreateNewSite(SPWeb web, string sSiteName,string sSiteTemplate)
    {
        string sSiteUrl = web.Url + "/" + sSiteName;

        if (!SiteExists(sSiteUrl))
        {
            try
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;



                string url = sSiteName;
                string title = sSiteName;
                string description = sSiteName + " Site Testing";
                string type = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SiteTemplateId"];



                // Site creation with unique permissions
                SPWebCollection webs = web.Webs;
                SPWeb newWeb = webs.Add(url, title, description, 1033, type, true, false);


                newWeb.Navigation.UseShared = true;

                //Adds to site navigation
                SPNavigation nav = newWeb.ParentWeb.Navigation;
                SPNavigationNode node = new SPNavigationNode(newWeb.Title, newWeb.ServerRelativeUrl);
                node = nav.AddToQuickLaunch(node, SPQuickLaunchHeading.Sites);

                //Adds to top quick link
                SPNavigationNodeCollection topnav = web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar;
                node = topnav.AddAsLast(node);

                // Changing the request access email to current user
                newWeb.RequestAccessEmail = newWeb.CurrentUser.Email;

                // Save changes
                newWeb.Update();

                newWeb.Close(); 
                // Disposing new web object
                //newWeb.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's definitely no differences in this area (what I call the "core SharePoint API") between Foundation and Server.
The problem is clearly elsewhere. Do you get an error, or simply nothing happens? I bet the latter, and consequently the problem would be in `SiteExists(sSiteUrl)`. Are you sure `sSiteUrl` is a different one the second run? Can't you have a `IsPostBack`/control initialization problem that leads to reading the same value from teh `TextBox`?

Comment: Yes i'm getting an error "Save Conflict. Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes." when adding the site. But the site is created first time.

Comment: Do you know where the error happens? On `webs.Add`? Do you have the call stack? (by the way I lost my bet... :p)

Comment: Also, what do you have to do to reset state to "first time", so the Web part works again? IISRESET? And another thing: what Template do you try to instantiate?